# How can I get a Delta in Noto using fontspec?

Tags: fontspec, unicode, noto

Using this MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\begin{document}

∆
\sffamily
∆
\end{document}
```

I get the error that the delta is not available with Noto:

> Missing character: There is no ∆ (U+2206) in font
> NotoSerif:mode=node;script= latn;language=dflt;+tlig;!
> {/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
> Missing character: There is no ∆ (U+2206) in font
> NotoSans:mode=node;script=l atn;language=dflt;+tlig;!

Is there a workaround or shouldnt I use Noto?

Comment: Maybe, Δ (U+0394) works? The shapes of the Greek capital letter Delta (U+0394) and the increment sign (U+2206) are virtually the same.

Comment: You are not using Delta but the Math Increment Operator,which do you want?

Comment: I need a Delta. Which I now understand, that I inserted the wrong letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U+2206 is the Math Operator INCREMENT. Noto does not yet have a Math font but this range is in several Noto font sets including CJK JP

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif CJK JP}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans CJK JP}
\begin{document}

∆
\sffamily
∆
\end{document}
```

But you probably wanted Delta,U+0394

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\begin{document}

Δ
\sffamily
Δ
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, I get `! Package fontspec Error: The font "NotoSerifCJKJP" cannot be found.` Is it not part of TeXLive?

Comment: @lukascbossert no I must have got it at some point. Noto collection is _massive_ and texlive only has a basic version (which already takes up a reasonable proportion of texlive size) all the Noto fonts are freely available